# Is $\{a_n X_n +c\}$ this sequence bounded in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ converge weakly to standard normal distribution. Now we define a sequence $\{a_nX_n +c\}$ like that where $c>0$ is any constant and $a_n\rightarrow\infty$. Can we conclude that this sequence is bounded in probability? Or how to proof that this sequence unbounded in probability?

Here bounded in probability of a sequence of r.v. means

> For all $n$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M>0$ such that
> $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > M) < \epsilon$$

Comment: How would you do it? What's your definition of bounded in probability? And so, how do you test it?

Comment: @Exodd I defined the bounded in probability.

Comment: Can you show what happens in case $X_n$ are all standard normal? That's a special case for your question. There you know how to compute $\Bbb P(|a_nX_n + c| > M)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not bounded in probability. Take $X_n =X$ for all $n\geq 1$, where $X$ is a standard normal random variable. Clearly, $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$. Now take $a_n=n$, and $c=0$ then
$$
\mathbb{P}(|a_nX_n+c|>M) = \mathbb{P}(|nX|>M) = \mathbb{P}\left(|X|>\frac{M}{n}\right)\to 1,
$$
as $n\to \infty$.